# Possible bug in profile - consecutive days

Tags: bug

When I look at my profile, the "# of consecutive visits" value seems to be off.  I hit this site every day, and a few times my consecutive visits has been reset to one.  Happened again today, and I am as sure as I can be that I visited yesterday.

Comment: [Jeff Atwood posted on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485) that merely hitting the site front page isn't enough. I don't know whether that's your situation, but it is something to consider.

Comment: Also, consecutive days start and end at midnight UTC, which for a lot of us is 8 PM during daylight savings time.  Hence, if you check in at 4 PM one day, then 9 PM the next, you miss a day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that much activity from your user in the past few days (e.g. only a couple of days in March).

Is it possible that you are visiting from a different device, and that is maybe logged in to a different user?

Comment: Nope. I use this computer, and hit all my web sites every day before work, and generally after work too.  There was one day maybe a month ago where I'm pretty sure I missed (I didn't check in the morning, and then arrived home well after 9 EST) but otherwise, I'm at least checking the front page of the chess site every day.

Comment: To be more clear, there are no hits from your user or IP on those days. I am not really sure why, but you don't seem to be there.

Comment: @TonyEnnis do you clear your cookies and forget to login again?